# Can IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS set on database level?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I have to investigate problems caused by IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON, can I focus on Client tools setting IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON or ANSI_DEFAULTS ON or can this be set for the whole database affecting all clients?

I can avoid the problem by changing my standard script header to

```
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS  OFF
```

but at which levels session, database, server can this setting be influenced?

**Edit:**

I found this [in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx)

it seems to be possible to set this on server level.

In the Server Properties dialog (Connections Page) I found the option changed and scripted it:

implicit transactions on:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'2'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

implicit transactions off:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'0'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

But executing

```
exec('dbcc useroptions')
```

in SSMS didn't reflect the change. The server setting seems to be somehow overwritten for such connections.

Now I have to repose the question,

**are there clients which do not overwrite the server setting and can crash when the server setting is changed.**

Answer (score 5):

Implicit transactions is a connection setting, it'll be set by the client tools and/or in the scripts only.